# How to POST XML using RestTemplate

Tags: java, web-services, spring

I intend to POST an XML message using Spring Rest Template. After a number of failures, I am starting to doubt whether Spring Rest Template can POST an XML message. This is a Restful client that I developed. The RestTemplate is intended to do an HTTP post of an XML to a RestFul webservice:

```
 Class RestClient{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();


    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();

    //This JAXB Message converter is intended to marshal an XML message over HTTP.
    //However, I find this converter is not doing the intended function.

    Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter jaxbMessageConverter = new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter();
    List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    mediaTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    jaxbMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypes);
messageConverters.add(jaxbMessageConverter);
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
restTemplate.postForLocation("http://localhost:8080/RecipeProject/restCallConsumer", "<add><somefield></somefield></add>",String.class);
   }
```

}

This controller is intended to consume the XML message. The controller was written to test that the client can send the XML message appropriately:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
@Controller
public class HomeController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/restCallConsumer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String restCallConsumer(String anXML) {
System.out.println("anXML: " + anXML);  
return "aView";
 }
}
```

Most of the example I found around using XML with RestTemplate involves using an object mapping tool. This tool maps object to an XML and vice versa. In my case, I only have an XML string that I want to send via HTTP post. Has anyone accomplished what I am trying to do ? It could be that RestFul client is not intended for what I am trying to do. Any answer would be appreciated :)

**EDIT**

THe XML message is produced by serializing a Map using Xstream. This is the code that does that:

```
    com.google.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap.ListMultimap<String, String> multimap = com.google.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap.LinkedListMultimap.create();
multimap.put("x", "1");
multimap.put("x", "2");
multimap.put("y", "3");

XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
xStream.registerConverter(new MapEntryConverter(xStream.getMapper()));

xStream.alias("add", multimap.getClass());
String xml = xStream.toXML(multimap);
System.out.println(xml);
```

This code is intended to convert the multimap into an XML string using a converter named MapEntryConverter. This is the code for the Converter:

```
public static class MapEntryConverter extends MapConverter {

public MapEntryConverter(Mapper mapper) {
    super(mapper);
}

public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
    return ListMultimap.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}

public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer,
    MarshallingContext context) {

    ListMultimap<String, String> map = (ListMultimap<String, String>) value;
    for (String key : map.keys()) {
    writer.startNode(key);
    writer.setValue(map.get(key).get(0));
    writer.endNode();
    }
}

}
```

**EDIT**

I change my code as per @artbristol recommended. I saw this in the log file:

DEBUG: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [
  1
  1
  3
] using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@1d34263a]

It looks like the restTemplate is POST-ing the XML message. However, the anXML parameter in the controller is null. Does this mean that the XML message could not reach the controller ? Could it be that the controller is not implemented correctly ?

Comment: May I know why you expecting it under anXMLMessage field ?  Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118670/sending-multipart-file-as-post-parameters-with-resttemplate-requests

Comment: @Rudy the XML message itself will be produced by serializing a Map using XStream. I'll add that information to my question. Thank you for the link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use Spring's JAXB marshalling message converter - you've already done the work by making it into a `String`. Just POSTing the `String` (like in your code) ought to work (lose the `String.class` argument though, that's intended for URL variables, and get rid of the `setMessageConverters` call, because that is preventing the default `StringHttpMessageConverter` from working).

Comment: It look like it works :) However, I could not print out the XML message in the controller. The XML message is null. I added more info in my question. Thank you @artbristol

Comment: I noticed that the `StringHttpMessageConverter` by default adds the HTTP header `Content-Type: text/plain` rather than your desired `text/html` - configuring that correctly (in the way you configured the `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` in your question) might fix it

Comment: @artbristol I also have similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758462/how-to-post-xml-data-through-resttemplate-in-the-body-of-request) on `RestTemplate`. If possible, can you help me out? I am stuck on that for a while and not able to understand how to make it work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.