# Tunneling MultipartFile

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, multipart

I have a `spring` controller that accepts a class named `FileUploadBean` on `POST`. The controller method looks like that:

**First Controller**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> uploadFile(final FileUploadBean fileUploadBean) throws IOException {
   // Some code that works fine here
}
```

One of the `FileUploadBean` properties is of type `MultipartFile`.

Now, I'm trying to add some sort of wrapper controller (that will run on another server) that also accepts `FileUploadBean` and just forwards the request to the first controller:

**Second (wrapper) Controller**:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> uploadImage(final FileUploadBean fileUploadBean) throws IOException {
  ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.postForEntity([first controller url here], fileUploadBean, byte[].class);
  return response;
}
```

When I'm sending the request to the first controller I get:

> ```
> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
> ```
>
> Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class
>   java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create
>   BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
>   SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain:
>   com.outbrain.images.beans.FileUploadBean["file"]->org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile["fileItem"]->org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem["inputStream"]->java.io.FileInputStream["fd"]);
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer
>   found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to
>   create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
>   SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain:
>   com.outbrain.images.beans.FileUploadBean["file"]->org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile["fileItem"]->org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem["inputStream"]->java.io.FileInputStream["fd"])
>         at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal

How can I make this request work?

Comment: Jackson is blowing up because it cannot serialize the objects that make up the MultipartFile or one of it's sub-properties.  You could re-architect your method to not use a REST service and just post the files like normal, sans wrapper `FileUploadBean`.

Comment: @CodeChimp - Could you elaborate on your solution? I did not quite get it

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118670/sending-multipart-file-as-post-parameters-with-resttemplate-requests

Comment: @holmis83 - Thanks! Already saw this one though and it didn't help me enough. Also there's no accepted answer there.

Comment: Change the method to accept a simple form post with MultipartFile instead of what appears to be a REST call sending JSON.  The problem is you are trying to call the first controller via what looks like a RESTful call, which I assume is accepting JSON given the error message.

Comment: @CodeChimp - You're right. I also saw it in another question. I will soon update a full answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, after some struggling this is how I solved it. That's what I did in the second controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<byte[]> uploadImage(final FileUploadBean fileUploadBean) throws Exception {
  File file = null;
  try {
    final MultiValueMap<String, Object> requestParts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

    final String tmpImageFileName = IMAGE_TMP_DIR + fileUploadBean.getFile().getOriginalFilename();
    file = new File(tmpImageFileName);
    fileUploadBean.getFile().transferTo(file);
    requestParts.add("file", new FileSystemResource(tmpImageFileName));

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"); // Sending it like the client-form sends it

    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(ImageUrlUtils.getUploadUrl(), HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(requestParts, headers),
      byte[].class);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(response.getBody(), response.getStatusCode());
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>((ex.getMessage).getBytes("UTF-8"),
      HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  } finally {
    if (file != null && file.exists()) {
      file.delete();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Ranjeet - I'm glad to know that :)

Comment: @SumeetSharma - great to hear!

Comment: Thanks for this, took me a good while until I saw this approach

Answer (score 1):

I debug previous answer, and found this solution without save file to file system

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload")
public ResponseEntity<Object> upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    final MultiValueMap<String, Object> requestParts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

    request.getParameterMap().forEach((name, value) -> requestParts.addAll(name, asList(value)));
    request.getMultiFileMap().forEach((name, value) -> {
        List<Resource> resources = value.stream().map(MultipartFile::getResource).collect(toList());
        requestParts.addAll(name, resources);
    });

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestParts, request.getRequestHeaders());
    return restTemplate.exchange(ImageUrlUtils.getUploadUrl() + "?" + request.getQueryString(),
                                 request.getRequestMethod(), requestEntity, Object.class);

}
```