# Spring Integration ServiceActivator output

Tags: spring-integration

Using the same setup as described in [Resttemplate : HttpMessageNotWritableException: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103070/resttemplate-httpmessagenotwritableexception-no-serializer-found-for-class-ja) I can't get the response from the backend API, the goal is to upload a file via HTTP and store it in MongoDB, when needed retrieve it via a GET call with certain http headers (which works).

The method inside the service activator returns the same request message... changing the return type from a Document to a Message with a Document in the payload but it isn't generating different behavior, basically the file is saved in MongoDB (the http call worked), but no response is sent to the front end.

On the other hand, using a pure XML config, I'm not sure how to extract the file from UploadedMultiPartFile and forward it to the backend API (see another setup below).

```
public Document uploadFile(Message inMessage) throws IOException {

LinkedMultiValueMap<String,Object> multipartRequest = (LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>) inMessage.getPayload();

final String filename = ((UploadedMultipartFile) multipartRequest.getFirst("file")).getOriginalFilename();

RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
MultiValueMap<String, Object> multipartMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
multipartMap.add("name", filename);
multipartMap.add("filename", filename);

byte[] bytes = ((UploadedMultipartFile) multipartRequest.getFirst("file")).getBytes();
ByteArrayResource contentsAsResource = new ByteArrayResource(bytes){
    public String getFilename(){
        return filename;
    }
};

multipartMap.add("file", contentsAsResource);
Document result = template.postForObject("http://localhost:5050/api/upload", multipartMap, Document.class);

return result; // which isn't null!

}
```

Request/Response headers

```
Remote Address:::1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/gateway
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ro;q=0.6,nb;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:55705
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary93sxUpjZ6rxmxsGc
Cookie:m=1933:86400%7C1800|2377:small|2491:chart|3247:t|34e2:|47ba:t|1d98:t|2a03:t|745a:t|77cb:t|5cf4:t|ca3:t|54e1:t|4e71:small|e69:chart|45b9:86400%7C1800|4a01:t|4c1b:t|3eff:t; JSESSIONID=8ACC161B9338DC122564C8BAB81EF25D
DNT:1
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:chrome-extension://cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn
service:file-ul
urlpath:upload
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundary93sxUpjZ6rxmxsGc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="a3YxYwN_460s.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary93sxUpjZ6rxmxsGc--
Response Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ro;q=0.6,nb;q=0.4
Content-Length:55705
Content-Type:multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary93sxUpjZ6rxmxsGc
Cookie:m=1933:86400%7C1800|2377:small|2491:chart|3247:t|34e2:|47ba:t|1d98:t|2a03:t|745a:t|77cb:t|5cf4:t|ca3:t|54e1:t|4e71:small|e69:chart|45b9:86400%7C1800|4a01:t|4c1b:t|3eff:t; JSESSIONID=8ACC161B9338DC122564C8BAB81EF25D
DNT:1
Host:localhost:8080
http_requestMethod:POST
http_requestUrl:http://localhost:8080/gateway
Origin:chrome-extension://cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn
Server:Jetty(8.1.15.v20140411)
service:file-ul
urlpath:upload
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
```

XML Setup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd">

<bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>

<bean id="headerMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
    <property name="inboundHeaderNames" value="*"/>
    <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="*"/>
    <property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value=""/>
</bean>

<int:channel id="http.frontend.rx"/>
<int:channel id="http.frontend.tx"/>
<int:channel id="http.backend.mysql"/>
<int:channel id="http.backend.mongo"/>

<int-http:inbound-gateway
        id="frontEndToMySQLXX"
        request-channel="http.frontend.rx"
        reply-channel="http.frontend.tx"
        header-mapper="headerMapper"
        path="/gateway"
        supported-methods="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE"/>

<int:router id="frontEndRouter" input-channel="http.frontend.rx" expression="headers.service">
    <int:mapping value="json" channel="http.backend.mysql" />
    <int:mapping value="file" channel="http.backend.mongo" />
</int:router>

<int-http:outbound-gateway
        id="toMongoDB"
        request-channel="http.backend.mongo"
        reply-channel="http.frontend.tx"
        url="http://localhost:5050/api/{path}"
        http-method-expression="headers.http_requestMethod"
        header-mapper="headerMapper"
        expected-response-type="byte[]">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="path" expression="headers['urlpath']"/>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int-http:outbound-gateway
        id="toMySQLDB"
        request-channel="http.backend.mysql"
        reply-channel="http.frontend.tx"
        url="http://localhost:7070/api/{path}"
        http-method-expression="headers.http_requestMethod"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
        charset="UTF-8">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="path" expression="headers['urlpath']"/>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to finally handle multipart file uploads via a separate URL, create a fake endpoint in Spring MVC and post Multipart file to that URL and forward that request to the backend system, it would've been nice if I could handle multipartfileuploads through a http outbound gateway... but that's not the case.