# Spring MVC MultipartFile problems

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I am trying to run a simple controller with a method that will receive

- A String with a value
- A file (MultipartFile object)

After some investigation ([Sending Multipart File as POST parameters with RestTemplate requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118670/sending-multipart-file-as-post-parameters-with-resttemplate-requests)) I ended up adding into my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/REST/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My application context file

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize">
        <value>104857600</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxInMemorySize">
        <value>4096</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The controller looks like

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/image")
public class ImageController  extends RestApiController {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImageController.class);

@RequestMapping(value="/simple", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="multipart/form-data")
public @ResponseBody boolean save(
        @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,
        @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name) {

        //Some code here
    return true;
}
```

So far I have been able to run unit tests against the controller with no problem, but I seem to be stuck when it comes to create a real http request.

I have tried with POSTMAN, but after some investigation seems that it does not set the multipart/form-data header properly, I have tried removing it, and the problem persists.

I have also tried with CURL

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/content/REST/image/simple -F "file=@/home/jmoriano/Pictures/simple.jpeg" -F "name=someName" -v
```

I have also tried with a RestTemplate object

```
public Boolean update() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    try {
        FormHttpMessageConverter formConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
        formConverter.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF8"));
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(formConverter);
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();         httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json")));
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        parts.add("file", new FileSystemResource("/home/jmoriano/Pictures/simple.jpeg"));
        parts.add("name", "name");
        return restTemplate.postForObject("http://127.0.0.1:8080/content/REST/image/simple", parts, Boolean.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("Ouch!", e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Just to be clear, the problem is not in the "name" parameter, that one works fine, however the MultipartFile is empty.

By debugging the code, I managed to check the MultiPartFilter class which receives an HttpServletRequest object, such object has its "parts" attribute already empty there. So the problem seems to be related with the way I am making the request... seems that my postman/curl/java attempts have failed... do you see anything incorrect in my config?

Comment: Just a quick update, the problem was not related with my config, which was fine but with the fact that the webapp was using Struts2 AND SpringMVC, unfortunately the multipart requests were processed by Struts2 filters, so I needed to create a custom filter to exclude Struts2's filters from processing certain urls (the ones served by Spring MVC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should put the bean `multipartResolver` to your dispathcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

in the link you show above they use this bean, too.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"  
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">  
    <property name="maxUploadSize">  
        <value>104857600</value>  
    </property>  
    <property name="maxInMemorySize">  
        <value>4096</value>  
    </property>      
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I already had that into my code (forgot to mention it into the question...) any other ideas?