# How to configure spring boot resttemplate proxy for client and server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an architecture where my server component will be deployed on separate host and client component (UI) will be deployed on separate.

I am stuck with RestTemplate Proxy, can someone please help me how can I achieve it.

Below is the example, I am trying to follow, but not sure if its the right approach.

```
@Value("${generic.proxyHost}")
private String proxyHost;

@Value("${generic.proxyPort}")
private Integer proxyPort;

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {

    LOGGER.info("Setting up proxy with HOSTNAME => " + proxyHost + " and PORT => " + proxyPort);

    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();

    Proxy proxy= new Proxy(Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort));
    requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);

    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

Also it would be help if I can know how to handle multipart file request.

Any help will be greatly appericiated.

Comment: What’s your doubt? You need to consume an REST API on a separate server? Is there any error or are you just looking for an example?

Comment: Hi @Ricardo yes I need to consume REST API on separate host and I am just looking for an example. I just googled around the stuff but no luck

Comment: you can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273236/spring-resttemplate-and-proxy-auth

Answer (score 0):

> I need to consume REST API on separate host and I am just looking for an example. I just googled around the stuff but no luck

There's a nice tutorial about `Rest Template` at [Baeldung's blog](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-template).

You could use this simple example to understand how to use it:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String fooResourceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/spring-rest/foos";
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(fooResourceUrl + "/1", String.class);
assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), equalTo(HttpStatus.OK));
```

There's a plenty of examples in the article I linked above that will help you during your learn path.

> Also it would be help if I can know how to handle multipart file request.

I believe that [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408271/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-with-resttemplate-spring-mvc) has the information you need to start implementing this use case.

Cheers!