# Calling external api from spring boot with multipart/form-data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I am working in a project where i need to get the data out of image using ocr.
I am using ocr by third parties where I can upload file and get the data out of ocr.

I need to call this API through spring boot. This api is multipart/form-data.

I created a function which takes the file and try to create a request to post the file to the external api.
I am getting error

```
"message": "Type definition error: [simple type, class java.io.FileDescriptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: 

org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile[\"inputStream\"]->java.io.FileInputStream[\"fd\"])",
```

**Controller Method**:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/ocrImage")
    public  ResponseEntity<GenericResponse> ocrImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        Object ocrDataImage = ocrService.ocrImage(file);
        return ResponseBuilder.buildResponse(ocrDataImage , 0, "");
    }
```

**Service called**

```
public Object ocrImage(MultipartFile file) {

    // adding headers to the api
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    headers.set("x-key", API_KEY);

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    body.add("file", file);


    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity= new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Object result = restTemplate.postForEntity(EXTERNAL_API_ENDPOINT, requestEntity,
            String.class);

    System.out.println(result);
    return result;

}
```

When postForEntity is called, i Get the error mentioned above.

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Can you expand on this and add the method that calls this and creates the MultipartFile object?

Comment: @Kieveli i am not creating, i am using postman form data where i upload file and get in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by storing the file locally. 
While calling third party API, i gave the location of this file and it worked.

1. In Controller Method:

   ```
   @PostMapping(value = "/ocrImage")
   public  ResponseEntity<GenericResponse> ocrImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

       // I have created a function to store file locally and return the absolute path
       String fileName = fileStorageService.storeFile(file);

       // passing the filepath to the service method
       Object ocrDataImage = ocrService.ocrImage(fileName);
       return ResponseBuilder.buildResponse(ocrDataImage , 0, "");
   }
   ```
2. Service called

   ```
   public String ocrImage(String path) {

       // getting the file from disk
       FileSystemResource value = new FileSystemResource(new File(path));

       // adding headers to the api
       HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
       headers.set("x-key", API_KEY);

       MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
       body.add("file", value);


       HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity= new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

       RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
       String result = restTemplate.postForEntity(EXTERNAL_API_ENDPOINT, requestEntity,
           String.class).getBody().toString();

       System.out.println(result);
       return result;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To disable fail on empty beans since you are using springboot, you can set the following property :

**application.properties**

```
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false
```

or you can set it manually in object mapper like :

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = 
        new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
    return converter;
}
```

Comment: What I want is to solve the probelm of calling External multipart API from local API. If you can share insight on that too.

Comment: Perhaps this will be of help to you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408271/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-with-resttemplate-spring-mvc