# Liferay: How to post a file to /dlapp/add-file-entry using RestTemplate

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'd like to upload a file to the /api/jsonws/dlapp/add-file-entry endpoint that Liferay provides using RestTemplate. I receive a file in a Jersey API and I'd like to pass that on to Liferay, but am unable to do so. I've tried following [Sending Multipart File as POST parameters with RestTemplate requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118670/sending-multipart-file-as-post-parameters-with-resttemplate-requests) with no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to do so" and "with no luck"? You don't know to call the API, or initialize the request parameters or you make a call and get an error? Please be more specific in the question.