# Attachment option for a form in JSP

Tags: jsp

I have a form wherein I need to add attachment option. This attachment can be of any type with some size limit. How can I do the same using jsp?

Comment: What are you using on a back-end? Spring?  Do you need to send any other form parameters as well?

Comment: Yes, I am using Spring and have to send other form parameters too

Comment: In this case your question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118670/sending-multipart-file-as-post-parameters-with-resttemplate-requests.