# How to POST image.png with Java Spring like in Postman form-data

Tags: java, wordpress, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm writing a Java Application, which posts content to a wordpress Rest Api. However I have a problem with programmatically POST a ".png" file with Java SpringBoot, because I don't know how to add the form-data body to HttpEntity<>(**body**, headers);

I've accomplished this using Postman -> Body -> form-data ->"file":"myFile.png" 
**see screenshots:**
[headers in Postman here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzLhH.png)
[Body in Postman here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMjgg.png)

I've written this code in Java Spring:

```
private MediaResponse uploadMedia (File graphicsFile) {
    String uploadUrl =  baseUrl + mediaUrl;
    HttpHeaders headers = getHttpHeader();

    headers.add(headerKeyAuthorization, User.getInstance().getUsertoken());
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=image.png");
    headers.add("Content-Type", "image/png");

    ...
```

I thought about doing something like that:

```
Map<String, File> body = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("file", new File("image.png"));

HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

//not interesting in this case
//excecuteMediaRequest(uploadUrl, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity);
```

to add the file to the body.

**Now my question is:** which "key":"value" pairs I have to set in the header(HttpHeaders), and how can I add the file to the body to achieve the same POST like in Postman?

My actual solution of course produces an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.util.HashMap] and content type [image/png]
```

## Solution:

I've get it to work with a little workaround and @Ajit Somans help. Here is the code that works for my scenario. Note that the methods *generateBytArray()*, *executeMediaRequest()* and the class *MediaResponse* are self written.

```
/**
 * Uploads media to a rest resource.
 *
 * @param graphicsFile the media file which should be uploaded
 * @return a MediaResponse which has access to resource urls and media information.
 */
private MediaResponse uploadMedia (File graphicsFile) {
    String uploadUrl =  baseUrl + mediaUrl;
    final String filename = graphicsFile.getName();
    //create headers for form data
    HttpHeaders header = getHttpHeader();
    header.set(headerKeyAuthorization, User.getInstance().getUsertoken());
    header.set("Content-Disposition", "form-data;");

    //produces a byte array resource
    ByteArrayResource contentAsResource = new ByteArrayResource(generateBytArray(graphicsFile)){
        @Override
        public String getFilename(){
            return filename;
        }
    };

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    formData.add("file", contentAsResource);
    //create request entity with header and body
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(formData, header);
    //executes request with in custom method.
    MediaResponse respondingObject = executeMediaRequest(uploadUrl, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity);
    return respondingObject;
}
```

As you can see, we don't set the *"Content-Type"* option, but set the *"Content-Disposition"* to *"form-data"* instead of *"attachment"*. The Key Part is to convert the media File, which is .png, into a *byte[]*. After that we produce a ByteArrayResource like mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118670/sending-multipart-file-as-post-parameters-with-resttemplate-requests). At least we're just setting the byte array into the body and execute the request to the given url endpoint.

here the method to convert a *File* into a *byte[]*:

```
 /**
 * generates a byte Array of a file.
 *
 * @param file the file to generate a byte array of.
 * @return byte array of the given file.
 */
private byte[] generateBytArray(File file) {
    byte[] res = new byte[0];
    try {
        //File file = fileResource.getFile();
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
        res = baos.toByteArray();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return res;
}
```

And the excecuting method:

```
    /**
 * Method to execute a Request to a Rest Api where we want to upload media to.
 *
 * @param url the url endpoint of the resource, where we upload the media file.
 * @param method the http request method, which ist POST in this case.
 * @param entity the http entity where header and body are stored.
 * @return a MediaResponse which has access to resource urls and media information.
 */
private MediaResponse executeMediaRequest(String url, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity entity) {
    ParameterizedTypeReference<MediaResponse> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<MediaResponse>() {};
    ResponseEntity<MediaResponse> response = template.exchange(url, method, entity,
            responseType, MediaResponse.class);

    MediaResponse responseObject = response.getBody();
    logger.info("\n ******** POST MEDIA from response with param: \n " +
                    "Post id: '{}' \n " +
                    "Post REST resource endpoint: '{}' \n" +
                    "Post Permalink '{}'\n *********",
            responseObject.getMediaID(), responseObject.getRestSelfUrl(), responseObject.getPermalink());

    return responseObject;
}
```

Thanks @Ajit Soman

Comment: Could you try to upload your png image without setting `content-type:image/png` in postman

Comment: @AjitSoman Yea that works, too. If I do it with Java and Spring like you mentioned in your answer I get a `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error`. If I set the "Content-Type" programmtically to "image/png" I get a  `Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap] and content type [image/png]` error. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LinkedMultiValueMap` instead of `Map` also use `FileSystemResource` instead of `File`. Your file upload code may look like this:

```
    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    map.add("file", new FileSystemResource("FILE_LOCATION"));
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Content-Type", "image/png");
    .. other headers...
    HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new    HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>>(
                        map, headers);
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    String result = template.postForObject("FILE_UPLOAD_URL",requestEntity, String.class);
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
```

Comment: I tested that and got a `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap] and content type [image/png]` exception, also if I set the `Content-Type` to `application/json`. If I don't add the `headers.set("Content-Type", "image/png");` I got a `500 Internal Server Error`. I've added MessageConverters `FormHttpMessageConverter` `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to even get to the 500 error. Any ideas?

Comment: remove this line :`headers.set("Content-Type", "image/png");` and try again

Comment: I did it and it helped, thanks. I edited my post with the solution, which works for me.