# Spring Resttemplate : how to post file and common String data at the same time

Tags: spring-mvc, resttemplate

I meet a request to upload files with spring resttemplate to upload files 
with http header "multipart/form-data", also some other normal parameters need to be posted. how to implements that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### you can use the following code in your application to have both multipartfile and normal request parameters at the same time.

- Replace the url with your own.
- replace param and value according to your normal parameters.

  `String url ="http://example.com";
  String fileAbsPath ="absolute path of your file";
  String fileName = new File(fileAbsPath).getName();
          Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileAbsPath));
          MultiValueMap<String, Object> data = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
          ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileAbsPath))) {
              @Override
              public String getFilename() {
                  return fileName;
              }
          };
          data.add("file", resource);
          HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
          requestHeaders.set("file","application/pdf");
          UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
                  .queryParam("param1", "value1")
                  .queryParam("param2", "value2")
          HttpEntity<> entity = 
                  new HttpEntity<> (data, requestHeaders);
          RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
          ResponseEntity<String> result =restTemplate.exchange(
                  builder.toUriString(), 
                  HttpMethod.POST, 
                  entity, 
                  String.class);
          System.out.println(result.getBody());`

Comment: I too had this issue, i tried it but i am getting:
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code.

```
   HttpHeaders headers = getCASHeaders(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
   LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
   params.add("fileField", new FileSystemResource(""));//get file resource
   params.add("stringfield", stringPayload);
   HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(params, headers);
   ResponseEntity<CasAssetApiResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
```

This will send post call with two param, you can add more according to your wish.

Please have a look at this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19108432/3892213) as well

Comment: but in this way,the value of 'stringfield' is a LinkedList, not a String....,  their api does recognize the value...

Answer (score 0):

I got the error "cannot be cast to java.lang.String" although my code does not have any casting.

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.